# How to set up parent and child tables (per category properties) in MySQL?

Tags: sql, database

I have a classified ad website. Users may put classifieds in, and each category has sub options.

Example: the user picks "car", and has to fill in options such as color, mileage, fuel, gearbox etc.

Here are my tables for this:

```
Category table:
cat_id (PK)
cat_name // "Cars" for example

Category Options table:
option_id (PK)
cat_id (FK)
option_name // "Color" for example

Option Values table:
value_id (PK)
option_id (FK)
value // "red" for example
```

My question is, in the last table (option values), shouldn't there be "something else" too, because how do I increase this table or reference this table to the classified?

For example, let's look at two records in these tables. First is Category table:

```
  Cat_id         Cat_name
     1            cars
     2            trucks
```

Then there is the Category Options table:

```
 option_id        Cat_id(FK)       option_name
     1              1                color
     2              1                mileage
```

Then the option values table, here is the problem, I don't know how to :

```
  Value_id       option_id(FK)    value
     1               1            red
     2               2          11000 miles
```

Then what happens if I decide to insert another advert with another car? Shouldn't there be another reference in the last table?

I also have other tables such as "classified" which contains headline, text, price etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already gave the answer yourself.

> Shouldn't there be another reference
>   in the last table?
>
> I also have other tables such as
>   "classified" which contains headline,
>   text, price etc...

Put the ID of the table `classified` as another key in the table options, so that you get

```
Option Values table:
value_id (PK)
option_id (FK)
classified_id (FK)
value // "red" for example
```

Then you can get all values for all options for a specified classified:

```
SELECT c.option_name, o.value
FROM option_Values o
LEFT JOIN category_options c ON (o.option_id=c.option_id)
WHERE o.classified_id = 15; -- as an example
```